# eSQL - Appending an array from an external query

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm new with eSQL and my IBM resource doesn't seem to have the answer. I currently have this code which is gathering Transaction IDs from an ODM response;

```
SET rEnvVar.TransList[] = Select    qr.*:Transaction_Num
                                                    From rACHOutput.*:AlertResult[] as qr
                                                    Where qr.*:alertFlag = FALSE;
```

I need to append additional Transaction IDs from a DB2 database. I've built the query and I know how to use passthru but I can't figure out how to append the result onto the existing list (TransList). Any help with that would really be great.

For context, at the end of this I want to have a complete transaction list made up from the two transaction sources (ODM & Database) from which I will build the Analysis Director response.

Comment: There is surely a better way to do that, but I would do it that way: save the other IDs in another list, then build a third array by iterating the two lists in two loops.